# One class for few widgets

Tags: android, widget

I have few widgets in my application with different sizes. And for each widget I need set receiver android:name to different values (otherwise Android show only one first widget). So I need to create separate class with identical code for each widget. That is uneasily. How I can avoid this? May be I can create one parent class and inherit it for other widget classes?

My code:

Manifest:

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_1x1" />

    </receiver>

    <receiver android:exported="false"
        android:name=".WidgetHandler_4x4"
        android:label="Widget 4x4" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_4x4" />
    </receiver>
```

And WidgetHandler_1x1 / WidgetHandler_4x4:

```
    public class WidgetHandler_4x4 extends AppWidgetProvider {
        public static String ACTION_WIDGET_EDIT = "ActionWidgetEdit";

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
             RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

             Intent editIntent = new Intent(context, this.getClass());
             editIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_EDIT);
             PendingIntent editPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, editIntent, 0);
             remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.edit_button, editPendingIntent);

             appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_EDIT)) {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
             super.onReceive(context, intent);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more information, also code base if it is possible, so we can understand the problem. As I see it now I don't see a problem in creating one widget parent class and lots of child implementations.

Comment: But how to do it right? Can you give the example of parent and child classes?

Comment: Show me the code you have and I can make an example on that.

Comment: Please, look edited question.